# how to toggle two different radio button in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a requirement where I will display two radio buttons using MVVM Model. Assume it as A and B.
If a user selects A radio button B radio button should be unchecked.
if a user selects the B radio button A radio button should be unchecked.

Comment: This is what RadioButtons do by default when they belong to the same group. It works out of the box if they are child elements of the same parent.

Comment: Simple web search - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/radiobutton-in-wpf/

Answer (score 0):

As @Clemens and @Michel_Fehr has suggested, you will have to use the same group for both the radio buttons.
The code will look something like this:

```
<StackPanel Margin="10">
    <RadioButton GroupName="myGroup" IsChecked="True">A</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton GroupName="myGroup">B</RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```